# Particles - Objects Order

Tags: particles

What criterium blender uses for order of items on a "Dupli Group" list ?
Thank you for help.

[image]

Comment: Please make your goal clearer.  Perhaps if you state your larger goal people can help you.  Are you trying to created an animated text sequence?  Your question [What is the solver for list creation?] is difficult to understand to me. Some interpretations follow.  What is a [technique/script/addon] to get an animated text list?  What is the [algorithm] built into Blender for particle creation?  How can I create a list of text which appears on the screen line by line?  Please show the desired stages of animation in an image if possible.

Comment: I tried my best, sorry. Edited ...

Answer (score 1):

Use these arrows to reorder them to your liking. They will spawn in that order (if pick random is not checked ofc):

[image]

If you need to do this on hundreds of objects do it witch python:

```
import bpy

# change the active item to be moved (the blue highlighted row in upper image)
bpy.data.particles["ParticleSettings"].active_dupliweight_index = 1

# move it up or down:
bpy.ops.particle.dupliob_move_up()
bpy.ops.particle.dupliob_move_down()
```

Comment: That is not my question. Please see highlighted text in my post. I'm not looking for solution here, I would like to understand the system. Anyway as i wrote, I have a lot of text objects. Try to reverse order of 100 manually ... And this is not a final version of text. Later I will have to do it again with finalised version.

Comment: @vklidu The highlighted text doesn't make much sense, and the rest of the text is about your need to change emitting order. If you need to do this on hundreds of objects you probably need python. Also the initial order is alphabetical, same as in Outliner. If this is what you need pls adjust the question so other people will answer what you want. I'll add the python part.

Comment: I don't think you are right with alphabetical order. It seems to me like it has something to do with order of adding objects into scene.

Comment: @vklidu you might be right, just did another different test and it is reverse order of adding into scene. But I am not still sure if this is always like this.